# Drop Down List Size

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a silly question and can't seem to get a solution.

I would like to allow the user to change the size of a combo box drop down list as per the image.

How would I do this?

[image]

Comment: I doubt that this is possible with the standard Microsoft WinForms controls.

Comment: may be this is what you're looking for http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5801/Adjust-combo-box-drop-down-list-width-to-longest-s or try this
ComboBox1.DropDownList.Height = ComboBox1.Items.Count * ComboBox1.Items.Height